# Not able to access a file on reboot in Android

Tags: android, file, file-io

I am developing an app where I load my settings of the app by reading an xml file stored in the external storage. But whenever I reboot the system, I am not able to access the xml for the first time, my app crashes because of this and restarts. from then it can access the xml file. Any clue on whats happening, or what I am doing wrong?

My sample code to open the file:

```
filepath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
File file = new File(filepath+"/xy.xml");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if the External Storage is available. Use a broadcast receiver, listen for Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED : Broadcast Action: External media is present and mounted at its mount point.

Comment: hi iago , I tried what you suggested , but the intent doesn't fire at the right time ,
 I would like to clarify that the External Storage in my device is not an external pednrive or sdcard plugged in , the  part of memory on the device is partitioned by the manufacturer as external storage. when I use 
"filepath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();"

i get the file path. I hope you suggestion for using Broadcast receiver should work in this case also. could you explain me if there are any other possibilities for this.

Comment: If such is the case maybe the system is detecting multiple external storage. Check the path that the API is returning for you. Internal storage when treated as SD card returns something like /mnt/sdcard/ so at the start when device is booting up the partition is not mounted, so you might be getting null pointer exception. In worst case you can still have a polling approach to keep checking the file till you don't get an exception.